# The authorization method of One Drive

Tags: oauth-2.0, arm, onedrive

I would like to know if One Drive supports those four ways of Authorization. Please refer to this link.  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-23

We are integrating our DVR and NVR with One Drive now and we need to understand which authorization method One Drive supports. We are trying to use OneDrive with embedded ARM processors, so the user does not have access to a browser as they would for a web-app.

Please kindly advise how we should proceed from here. Thanks for your time and I look forward to hearing from you.

Best Wishes,
Ted Yang

Comment: Not really clear exactly what you're asking. You authorize OneDrive with your Microsoft Account. Have you explored their API documentation? https://dev.onedrive.com/

Comment: Hi Dan,

Yes, We did check the API. https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm. But the authorization is through web interface. We would like to know if other ways of authorization are supported, like http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#page-23 Thanks.

Comment: I would also ask what language and system you are trying to write this with? Is this embedded c in a microcontroller?

Comment: Yes. it is embedded C in the ARM. Thanks.

Comment: And I'm guessing you want the customer to be able to store things on their own OneDrive? So their username and password are in the program, and then we store recorded files on OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to say yes, OneDrive probably supports those ways of authorization, because on their [authentication documentations page](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm) they say the following:

> The OneDrive API uses the standard [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) authentication scheme to authenticate users and generate access tokens.

That link takes us to the oauth.net site page for OAuth 2.0. On that page, we find the following:

> The final version of the spec can be found at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

which is the document you linked. The OneDrive API documentation says it supports OAuth 2.0, and your linking the definition of OAuth 2.0, so I think it's safe to say it's supported. How to use it is another question entirely, and one I am unable to answer.

I will note, however, that on the OAuth page, they have this to say about it's uses (emphasis mine):

> OAuth 2.0 focuses on client developer simplicity while providing specific authorization flows for **web applications**, **desktop applications**, **mobile phones**, and ***living room devices***.

I would presume that living room devices could include DVRs, and although your DVRs are for security purposes, the development of cloud storage APIs for either would undoubtedly be similar. So I would say this is probably quite possible.

---

**How to do it:**

First things first, you'll need to register your app. This gets you a `client id` and a `client secret` which you'll need. [Registration directions](https://dev.onedrive.com/app-registration.htm#register-your-app-for-onedrive)

There are two methods: token flow and code flow. Token flow is two steps, and code flow is three steps. However token flow uses tokens that expire, so it would require the user to reenter thigns periodically. You therefor want to use *code flow*. Here's some [directions for that](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#code-flow).

Basically the steps of the code flow are:

1. Get an `authorization code`
2. User `authorization code` to get an `access token`
3. User `access token` to make API calls

You WILL need to make HTTP requests. I'm sure you should be able to do this with ARM embedded C. However, step 1 is what gives you to the Microsoft account login page. I am note sure how to circumvent this, exactly. I'm not sure you're supposed to be ABLE to circumvent this, since Microsoft doesn't want you handling their customers' passwords.

They have an example in Javascript that might give useful details on oauth in the `oauth.js` file. [Javascript sample project](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-js)

Comment: Hi Dan,
  In OneDrive authentication and sign-in page, Step 1. Get an authorization code, it says "To start the sign-in process with the code flow, use a web browser or web-browser control to load this URL request."
  Is there anyway we can get the authorization code from OneDrive server without using web browser?
  Thanks for your time and help.

Best Wishes,
Ted

Comment: Hi Dan,  I really appreciate your time and help. I will discuss it with our R&D. Have a nice weekend. Ted

Comment: Glad I could be of some help. Good luck, that'll be an awesome product if it works out well!